# Multiple Apps in the same AWS Cognito user pool would the cognitoID be the same for same user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have a Cognito user pool that works fine with my iOS and Android apps. This pool has a client secret key. I now want to build authentication for web. The javascript sdk for cognito doesn't have support for user pools configured with app client secret.

So lets say I create a new app (without client secret) in the same pool to be used specifically for the web app. Would my mobile users who are currently part of App A in the pool, be able to log into Cognito via App B (the one I would configure for web)?

What is the recommended approach here to allow mobile users to still be able to log into cognito via web?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create a new app client on your User Pool for use with your web interface. User accounts are associated with the User Pool, and not associated with the client apps they use. A user account can authenticate against a User Pool using any properly configured app client. [The User Pool App Settings documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html) notes that you'd typically create a different app client for each platform, so making a different client for your web interface is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the AWS Console, go to:

1. Cognito
2. Manage User Pools
3. Choose the User pool
4. General Settings > App clients
5. Bottom left of the main display there is a link that says "Add another app client"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by creating separate "App Client" inside the same user pool.

This will allow you you to choose different mechanism for each app client to add.

[image]